# Restore single couchdb database on cluster environment

Tags: couchdb

I have been looking a way to restore single database in couchdb vesion 2.0.0 or best practice on restoring a single database.

The enviroment, 5x couchdb2.0.0 instances, cluster mode with sharding.

What I used to do in the past with a single couchdb without sharding is to replace the db.couch files and a database file.

However, with the replication and sharding, I found that the database behaves differently. After I copy the db.couch files and shards/ from backup, I was able to get the restored documents. However after I restart couchdb, it went back to the original as if the restored database never there.